# Conditional formatting depending on checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

**What I want to happen:**
Depending on whether a tick box is clicked or not the corresponding cell on the same row should be colored (box unchecked) - so it would look like this:

[image]

My best guess was doing the following:
[image]

Comment: would you consider a solution using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)?

Comment: I found a solution: The custom formula would be **=$G:$G=false**. Now as soon as the box is unchecked, E is formatted in the color I chose. If the box is checked (therefore "true"), formatting does not apply.

Comment: I tried your solution ant it's working in both ways for me. Can you share dummy spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

to color a whole row you need to freeze the column with `$`

```
=$G2=FALSE
```

applied to range **A2:Z**